# How do I secure API keys and requests on my Express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, fetch, xss

So basically, I have a sign in with Google Button in my html, and I need the following code:

```
<div id="g_id_onload"

        data-client_id=TOKEN HERE"

            data-callback="processResponse"

            data-context="continue-with"

            data-ux_mode="popup"

            data-auto_select="true">

        </div>
```

I have looked all over the internet, and I cannot find a good way to secure my client_id token. This is a general question that also applies to many other aspects of my website. For example, my front end html makes requests to add, change, and delete entries in a database, but anyone could send these requests and manipulate the database. How do I secure this?

I thought about process.env, but then anyone could open up the inspect element and type in console.log(process.env.TOKEN) to get it.

I also thought about requesting the backend server for the key, but I can't find a good way to authenticate the request because then anyone could send a fetch request to my backend for this key. I thought about putting some sort of "password" that is required to authenticate the request, but then this password would have to be contained in the html making it essentially useless.

Answer (score 2):

The `client_id` in OAuth2 flows is not a secret. A malicious user will not be able to do anything bad with a `client_id` alone. So, don't worry about hiding it.

As to your second question, if you have an API yourself you *do* need to secure that with bearer tokens or cookies. The question is too large to answer here, but plenty of tutorials have been written.

Comment: Do you know of any specific tutorials, or examples of how to accomplish the second thing? I just don't see how it's possible when the request is originating from the HTML, but any potential malicious people have full access to the HTML through Inspect Element. Thanks.

Comment: @CarrierReviews it *shouldn't* be an issue for others to see the source or requests. If I can see requests my browsers are making, why would that be a problem? After all, as a user I'm already making the request? Can you think of a scenario why that would be bad for you?

Comment: Because then users could send false requests to the server. For example, my html will only send acceptable requests to the server, but a user could send an unacceptable request to the server through the inspect element. Request.referrer would show it as coming from my site. Therefore, on the server side, I want to only accept trusted requests, but I have been having trouble establishing a system for differentiating trusted and untrusted requests.

Comment: @CarrierReviews what's your definition of a 'false request'. You need to make sure that people can't do things they are not supposed to. You don't do this based on where the request comes from. If I as a user make a manual request to delete my own data (something I was already able to do with the web interface) that's my choice, but I shouldn't be able to delete someone else's data for example. The server checks if the action I'm performing is allowed, but it doesn't matter if this is using your web application or postman.

Comment: That's actually a really good example of what I'm talking about. You could delete someone else's data, add unapproved data, etc. I think I'm starting to see where you're coming from though. I should be validating if the requests are acceptable on the server side and then it won't matter what requests get sent from the client side. Currently, I am only sending acceptable requests from the client side, and trusting all requests on the server side. I think that's the wrong approach. Do you have any recommendations on how I can use Continue with Google to ensure users only modify their own data?

Comment: @CarrierReviews yes, your API needs a form of authentication. The API needs to ensure that users can only perform operations they're allowed to. *How* you set all this up is a bit beyond the scope of this comment box I think, but this is quite common.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tips.